# find lowest and highest values in a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, max, min

I have the following hash

```
hash = {"CLIENT1"=>"12.89", "CLIENT2"=>"14.36", "CLIENT3"=>"12.57", "CLIENT4"=>"11.02", "CLIENT5"=>"12.53", "CLIENT6"=>"12.49", "CLIENT7"=>"12.32", "CLIENT8"=>"11.47", "CLIENT9"=>"13.60", "CLIENT10"=>"13.11", "CLIENT11"=>"8.43", "CLIENT12"=>"11.41", "CLIENT13"=>"11.06", "CLIENT14"=>"11.47", "CLIENT15"=>"6.53", "CLIENT16"=>"12.36", "CLIENT17"=>"11.86", "CLIENT18"=>"12.93", "CLIENT19"=>"11.54", "CLIENT20"=>"9.93"}
```

and when I do `hash.values.max` I get 9.93 - which is incorrect. `hash.values.min` also gives me an incorrect result of 11.02

Can any one tell me what could be wrong? If I issue the same command to a hash with only 10 clients, it works as expected.

Comment: It is correct. Nothing is wrong. The question is not clear.

Comment: Playing @sawa's game, it is not correct, as sylvian could not have got `9.93` or `11.02`, since the values are all strings. One does not need a mind-meld to know what the problem is.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I interpreted that the OP just didn't write the quotes (either because they didn't know the proper way to write here, or were lazy).

Comment: I know, @sawa. It wasn't meant as a criticism. I know you are only interested in improving standards. Keep it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the strings to floats (headslapper, eh?).

```
a = hash.values.map(&:to_f)
  #=> [12.89, 14.36, 12.57, 11.02, 12.53, 12.49, 12.32, 11.47,  13.6, 13.11,
  #     8.43, 11.41, 11.06, 11.47,  6.53, 12.36, 11.86, 12.93, 11.54,  9.93]
a.max => 14.36
a.min =>  6.53

"9.1" > "10.2" #=> true
 9.1  >  10.2  #=> false
```

Comment: hmm, headslapper. I knew those were strings, so ruby was returning the maximum values based on the string sequence?

Comment: Yes. Ruby uses the method `<=>` for ordering values.  Compare [Float#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Float.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), [String#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) and [Array#](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).

Answer (score 1):

I will do as below using [`#minmax_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by) method :-

```
 min, max = hash.minmax_by { |_,v| v.to_f }.map(&:last)
 min # => "6.53"
 max # => "14.36"
```

Comment: Better, definitely better.